# Unit testing spring controller using WEBMVC and using spring security with AAD resource

Tags: spring, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I have a spring controller setup with security linked to microsoft AAD, everything works, but im unable to test the controller because of security. I can use the filters=false in my test to bypass it. But i was wondering is there a way i can set up the spring security and my controller to test.

my classes:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration extends AadResourceServerWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.cors()
                .configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration() {{
                            setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "PUT", "PATCH"));
                            addAllowedHeader("*");
                            addAllowedOrigin("*");
                            setExposedHeaders(ImmutableList.of(
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
                                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                                    "Access-Control-Request-Method",
                                    "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
                                    "Access-Control-Max-Age",
                                    "Origin",
                                    "Content-Disposition",
                                    "X-Suggested-Filename",
                                    "Authorization",
                                    "x-xsrf-token",
                                    "Accept",
                                    "X-Requested-With",
                                    "Content-Type"
                            ));

                            setMaxAge(3600L);
                        }}
                );

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to store user's state.
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                // handle an authorized attempts
                .exceptionHandling()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, SessionManagementFilter.class);

                http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/v3/api-docs/**",
                        "/configuration/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/swagger-ui/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll() //Swagger needs all these for some reason

                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/**")
                        .hasAnyAuthority(
                               DEVELOPER_ROLE
                        )
        

                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

my controller

```
public class BasicController {

    @GetMapping(“/api/v1/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> test(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(“hello”);
    }
}
```

my test

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@WebMvcTest(BasicController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ServiceApplication.class})
public class BasicControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@MockBean
private AadResourceServerProperties aadResourceServerProperties;
@MockBean
private JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

@Test
public void test() {
    mockMvc.perform(get(“/api/v1/test”)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().json(“hello”));
}


}
```

Comment: Add `@WithMockUser` to add a user to your request so you have the proper authorities to execute this. Or add a JTW token to your request as a header. If you have security enabled you will have to cater for it in your tests.